# Setup apache multiple virtual hosts with fpm and docker

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker, docker-compose, fpm

Hi guys here is the issue, i'd like to have 2 virtual hosts on Apache: one pointing to www.mysite.com (php-fpm container) and the other pointing to www.mysite.com/blog (wordpress fpm container).

I'm using Docker with compose, the actual file is something like this

```
server:
  build: ./docker/apache
  image: server:latest
  links:
    - fpm
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  volumes:
    - webroot:/var/www/html/mysite.com

fpm:
  build: ./docker/php
  image: fpm:latest
  links:
    - database
  volumes:
    - webroot:/var/www/html/mysite.com  

database:
  build: ./docker/mariadb
  image: database:latest
  env_file:
    - ./docker/mariadb/env
  volumes:
    - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

wpdatabase:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
    - wpdbdata:/var/lib/mysql

blog:
  image: wordpress:4.9.1-php7.1-fpm-alpine
  links:
    - wpdatabase
```

What i've done so far is to add a link from the blog service to the server and changed the vhost file like this

```
## New host
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite.com:80
  ServerAlias mysite.com:80
  ServerPath /blog/
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://blog:9000/var/www/html/$1 timeout=120
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  ErrorLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/blog.log
</VirtualHost>
##

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite.com:80
  ServerAlias mysite.com:80
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite.com
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://fpm:9000/var/www/html/mysite.com/$1 timeout=120
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  ErrorLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

... but I keep getting `Not Found`

Help me! Thanks